# Is it possible to use a tuple as a dictionary key in Python YAML?

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

```
dictionary = {('x1','y1'): [1,2], ('x2','y2'): [4,5], ('x3','y3'): [6,7]}
```

How do I configure this kind of dictionary in Python YAML?

Comment: Maybe, if you have only strings in tuple, you can join them "_".join(a_tuple) and use resulting string as a key.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to create the your YAML file like:

```
!!python/tuple ['x1','y1']: [1,2]
!!python/tuple ['x2','y2']: [4,5]
!!python/tuple ['x3','y3']: [6,7]
```

And to load it:

```
import yaml

print yaml.load(stream=open("your_file_path", 'r'))
```

**Output:**

```
{('x1', 'y1'): [1, 2], ('x3', 'y3'): [6, 7], ('x2', 'y2'): [4, 5]}
```

To get some value you can use:

```
yaml_load[('x1', 'y1')]
```

And if you want to test it's a tuple just use:

```
type(yaml_load.keys()[0])
```

Comment: Is it possible to dump it with in this format "!!python/tuple ['x1','y1']: [1,2]"

Apparantly: {(1,2): [1,2,3]} == yaml.load(yamp.dump({(1,2): [1,2,3]}))